# Maximize method is not working for safari browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have been using

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

for maximizing the window browser. It works fine with other browsers i.e IE,Chrome,FireFox.
I have installed safari on my windows machine and trying to automate my application on safari.But Its not working with safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Glims` add on for maximizing safari(MAC OS). Look at the link : [Maximize safari browser](http://maclord.ozarweb.com/mevzu/how-to-maximize-safari-windows-to-full-screen-on-mac/)